# PouchDB offline authentication/login - Sync users with remote db?

Tags: authentication, couchdb, progressive-web-apps, pouchdb

I am working on a PWA using Vue.js. For syncing data we use PouchDB on the client and a remote express-pouchdb server.

When starting the application, we want the user to login, regardless if online or offline.

So our idea is the following:

1. When opening the website for the very first time, the user has to login at the remote-db
2. All users are synced to the local pouchdb-instance
3. When the PWA is opened and the client isn't online, then authenticate against the local-db, otherwise the remote-db (and also keep the users in sync).

Is it possible to achieve this behavior?
I've seen some authentication plugins, namely [pouchdb-authentication](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-authentication), [pouchdb-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-auth) and [pouchdb-seamless-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-seamless-auth), though im not exactly sure, if these can be used for our requirement.

Comment: I'm wondering why you even want the user to log in locally. Storing login credentials in the browser, even if they are hashed or encrypted, isn't such great idea. Instead, you could simply load the user's data automatically if a cookie/JWT is present and prompt to login if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by encrypting your pouchdb https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch

Then if you are offline instead of login you enter the password to decrypt. The problem is that if you are logged out when you open the app offline there is no way you can get user info.

So you need to store user info locally, in a _local document that doesn't replicate. And since offline authentication is not supported, you have to check yourself user/password stored locally. So you will have 2 separate login for online(you can do this easily with pouchdb authentication) and offline.

Personally the best solution is to make a dump of pouchdb on logout. And then delete local pouchdb (data in browser). If you are online, you proceed to standard login and upon success load the dump and sync to remote. If you are offline, check locally stored user/password and again upon success load dump.
Additionally, you can encrypt the dumped database as well.